# hapijs Joi when one field is non empty other fields must be required

Tags: hapi.js, joi

When the password is non empty means other two fields are required. In some cases password will be present but that will be null, on that cases other two fields are not required. I tried with exist() and !empty() but it doesn't work.

`password      : joi.string().trim().optional().description('Password'),
device_type   : joi.when('password', {is: (joi.exist() && !joi.empty()), then: joi.number().required().valid(validation.user.device_type.allowOnly).description('Device type')}),
device_token  : joi.when('password', {is: joi.exist(), then: joi.string().trim().required().description('Device token')})`

But this won't works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 parts to your question:

1. Treat an empty string for password the same as not having submitted a password at all.  See [any.empty(...)](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.0.2/API.md#anyemptyschema)
2. Require keys whenever another password is present. See [object.with(...)](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.0.2/API.md#objectwithkey-peers)

Putting them together and simplifying your schema for clarity (note all keys are optional by default):

```
const schema = joi.object({
    password      : joi.string().trim().empty(''),
    device_type   : joi.number(),
    device_token  : joi.string().trim()
}).with('password', ['device_type', 'device_token']);
```